# Woobat into Swoobat!

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I want to evolve my Woobat into a Swoobat on my X version, I've looked it up and I found out that it needs to have 'max happiness' and then level up. Anybody have any tips on how I could make Woobat happy? It's already holding a Soothe Bell and I fed it lots of PokePuffs and some premium berry juice too!

Comment: walk around in circles for a few days with it in your party, but check with the happiness-rater NPC first

Comment: Ok thanks! What town/city is the happiness rater in?

Comment: no idea I just know that the gens with happiness have one somewhere

Comment: Alright then, I'll go and have a look around

Comment: Just found out that the happiness rater is in Laverre City

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Pokepuffs do not increase happiness, they increase [affection](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon-Amie). The two, while similar sounding, are not related mechanically speaking. Brief research has yielded conflicting reports. [Bulbapedia has Poke Amie listed as a source of happiness](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness#Generation_VI), but it doesn't elaborate on what actions in the Amie raise happiness, or by how much.

Second, unless your its EVs are maxed, Colorful Shake is the only one that will raise happiness. The variously coloured juices will only increase happiness if the EVs are maxed, if not, it will increase the EVs for whichever stat it's color relates to. (Rare and Ultra Rare soda/juice will likely increase happiness through leveling up)

However, if you want to raise happiness in a hurry, one thing you can do is buy around 8 of each vitamin in Laverre City (use the discount O-Power for lower prices), stuff your pokemon full of them, get a massage from the house to the left of the pokemon center in Cyllage City, and round it all out with gaining a couple levels.

If you've already been doing some work towards raising the happiness, it would be wise to check with the breeder in the Pokemon Fan Club in Laverre city first, he is this game's Happiness checker. ([Bulbapedia has a handy table to translate what he says into useful information](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness#X_and_Y))

Comment: Ohhhh got it! Thanks! Already given my Woobat a Colourful Shake I just ave to give it massages and Vitamins? Ok

Comment: Vitamins may not be necessary if you don't have a lot of spare money. I just find them to be a quick boost if I'm in a hurry. Honestly, depending on the level of the pokemon, I find a quick run through the Battle Chateau while they're holding the soothe bell usually does the trick.

Comment: I usually go to the restaurants in Lumiose City

Comment: Don't forget EV reducing Berries ;)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, Woobat evolves by happiness and PokePuffs do not increase happiness, although they increase affection.

My way of evolving a Pokemon which evolves via happiness very quickly is to use EV reducing berries. They include [Pomeg Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/pomegberry.shtml), [Kelpsy Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/kelpsyberry.shtml), [Qualot Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/qualotberry.shtml), [Hondew Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/hondewberry.shtml), [Grepa Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/grepaberry.shtml), [Tamato Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/tamatoberry.shtml).

While they reduce the EVs of a Pokemon 10 points per use, you also get 10 happiness points per use for the first 100 happiness points, then 5 per use until you reach 200 happiness points and subsequently 2 per use.

The base happiness of a Woobat is at 70 points. To evolve, this must reach 220 points. If you hatched one, give it 34 berries and its happiness will be capped (only 29 if you give it berries in the same location you met it and a Soothe Bell brings it further down to 15 if both conditions meet and 14 if you have the level 3 O-Power active and all the previous conditions satisfy). If you had your Swoobat for some time now, it shouldn't take a lot berries to max out its happiness and you will only have to level it up once.

No cycling, not much waiting (just spam the berries until you can't anymore), and you know exactly when your Woobat is ready to evolve (this should take only a few seconds to a minute).

The only waiting part is that you have to plant a lot of the berries (shouldn't be hard if you plant a lot and water them regularly, or if you have planted a bunch before and you only need to use them now), and reset one of the EVs the Pokemon currently has. Usually, you will be better off with using a Kelpsy Berry for Swoobat, since it is more specially oriented than physically.

Answer (score 1):

Another method of raising happiness which I find a lot easier, is to use the Befriending O-power, combined with the soothe bell on your Pokémon. As steps taken count towards happiness, its easy to just activate the o-power and simply ride in circles to raise happiness:

1. Put the Soothe Bell onthe Pokemon who's happiness you wish to raise
2. Fly to the Center of Lumiose City
3. Activate your Bike
4. Activate Befriending O-power
5. Ride around the tower in circles until the O-power is completed (3 minutes).
6. Level up the Pokemon
7. Repeat from point 4 if necessary - Some Pokémon needed one O-power, others slightly more

I did this when working on completing the Kalos Pokedex, including with Woobat

Comment: @rlecaro - well, I did say 'point' 4 ;)

Comment: hahaha well, I counted once and got tired :/